# Run After Submit Script when approve button is clicked Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

When approve button is clicked on journal entry, this reversal should be auto approved. This script is running when i am clicking edit and then saving. I want this to run when just approve button is clicked without editing. How can i do that?

```
    function JEReversalAfterSubmit(type){

    if (type == 'approve')
   {
            var filters2 = new Array();
            filters2[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'tranid', null, 'is', 'JV267');
            var columns2 = new Array();
            columns2[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn( 'internalid' );
            var searchresults2 = nlapiSearchRecord( 'journalentry', null, filters2, columns2 );

            for ( var j = 0; searchresults2 != null && j < searchresults2.length; j++ )
            {
                var searchresult2 = searchresults2[ j ];
                var reversalJEID = searchresult2.getValue( 'internalid' );
                nlapiLogExecution('debug','reversalJEID',reversalJEID);
            }

            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','34','34');

            var params = new Array();
            params['type'] = 'approve';
            nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD','journalentry',reversalJEID, 'false',params);
        }
      }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the approve button created? If it is created via workflow, you can use a custom workflow action script for this instead of an User Event script.

Comment: we are not using any work flow. We have just enabled. REQUIRE APPROVALS ON JOURNAL ENTRIES at Accounting Preferences -> General subtab

Comment: When you click on the button, does it refresh the page?  If it does, you might be able to move your script to the Before Load Event, just validate first if the record is approved then do your logic.
  
Just be concious that this will affect the 'loading' of the screen so if your script takes to long, your users might complain.

Comment: Thanks for your help actually i was using default netsuite button. I think default netsuite button does not trigger any event. So I created a new custom approve button and hide the default and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard Approve button, you should be able to use `context.type === 'approve'` in a user event on after submit.